# Proc Import as Character from Excel Linux SAS

Tags: sas

I have a macro that I use to import Excel files from a Windows directory to SAS (version 9.3) on a Linux server. In general the macro has worked fine, but now I'm trying to import an Excel file with a column that contains mostly numeric data with some character records thrown in.

The variable looks something like this:

```
Var2
1111111
2222222
3333333
4444444
Multiple
5555555
H6666-01
```

The variable is getting read in as numeric so I'm losing the data in the fifth and seventh records. I've tried a few of the suggestions listed in [this answer](https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Procedures/PROC-IMPORT-EXPORT-forcing-column-to-be-character-or-numeric/td-p/132678), but nothing seems to change the variable type.

Here's a portion of the macro I have:

```
proc import replace
    out=&d_set
    dbms=excelcs
    file="\\path\to\file\&xlsx_nm";
    sheet="&sheet_nm";
    server="Server";
    port=0000;
    serveruser="&sysget_USER";
    serverpassword="&pw";
    range="&rng";
    DBDSOPTS = "DBTYPE=(Var2='CHAR(8)')";
run;
```

I just added the statement `DBDSOPTS = "DBTYPE=(Var2='CHAR(8)')";` based on the suggestion on the link above, but the output in the log did not change.

I have also tried padding the original Excel file with a "dummy" record (which I'd like to avoid) with character data in the column that I'm having issues with, but this also did not work.

I'd like to solve this in the import procedure but I'm open to other suggestions.

Comment: Try DBSASTYPE instead. If this is a one time issue, I would sort my data so that the characters where in the first row and then you don't have the issue. Or convert to a CSV.

Comment: `DBSASTYPE` does appear to change the data type, but the character values are still pulled through as missing. Sorting the data may be the only option.

Comment: What if you try DBMS=XLSX?  Also, are you running enterprise guide?

Comment: @Joe DBMS=XLSX causes other issues with the import. I think it may only be available on Windows SAS. And no, I don't have access to EG, or a GUI.

Comment: Can you set the TYPEGUESSROWS registry key on the PC Files Server?

Comment: Also - my understanding is DBMS=XLSX is compatible with Linux, if you license Access to PC Files. You may not license that, of course.